# Web API method Populate as @Html.DropDownList in MVC project's create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have following class

**Basic Class**

```
public class Basic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string NAME { get; set; }

}
```

I have following method to fill the Value to above class

**Get Authers Id and Name Method**

```
public IEnumerable<Basic> GetAuthersIdName()
{
     .....
}
```

So in Web API layer `Controller Class` I'm getting above details like below

```
    // GET: api/Authers/all

    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Authers/all")] 
    public IEnumerable<Basic> GetAuthersIdName()
    {
        return db.GetAuthersIdName();
    }
```

Then I can have following URL to fetch above details

```
http://localhost:13793/api/Authers/all
```

[image]

So In my MVC Layer , model folder I created a class to handle above details like below

```
public class LibraryClient
{
    private string AUTHER_URL = "http://localhost:13793/api/Authers";

    //DropDown

    public IEnumerable<Basic> GetAuthersIdName()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AUTHER_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("Authers/all").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Basic>>().Result;
            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I create Controller class to populate above details on front end like below

**Controller Class**

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    // GET: Books/Create
    public ActionResult Create()  
    {
        LibraryClient lc = new LibraryClient();
        ViewBag.listAuthers = lc.GetAuthersIdName();
        return View("Create");
    }

    // POST: Books/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Book book)
    {
        LibraryClient lc = new LibraryClient();
        lc.CreateBook(book);
        return RedirectToAction("BookswithAuthers", "BookWithAuther");
    }
}
```

**View File**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auther_Id, "Auther_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "." })
        <div class="col-md-10">               
            @Html.DropDownList("NAME", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listAuthers, "---Select---");
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auther_Id, "", new { @class = "." })
        </div>
    </div>
```

But since I'm using `IEnumerable<Basic>` to populate in business layer I cannot use that type in frontend.

I saw many answers do this task using jQuery and Web API , without that path how can I populate my drop down with `@Html.DropDownList()`

Comment: You don't really pass your data into your model, you pass it into your ViewBag. And then you try to read your model in your view, while you should read your ViewBag

Comment: Isn't it I'm calling `ViewBag.listAuthers = lc.GetAuthersIdName();` here

Comment: `ViewBag.listAuthers` is `IEnumerable<Basic>` not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - you can use `ViewBag.listAuthers = new SelectList(lc.GetAuthersIdName(), "ID", "Name")` to create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (or `ViewBag.listAuthers = lc.GetAuthersIdName().Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.ID.ToString(), Text = x.Name });`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now that populating it , to get ID value from that dropdown do I need to use like this `@Html.DropDownList("ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listAuthers, "---Select---");`

Comment: It does not matter whether its `ID` or `NAME` (it could be `XYZ`) - the value of your <select>` will be the `ID` of the selected `Basic`. But you should be passing a model to the view and binding to your model, not binding to an arbitrary value, and that model should also contain a property for the SelectList (refer the code in [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o))

Comment: @StephenMuecke but when I debug `POST` method of that I can see ID of that selected value not getting to model http://imgur.com/a/6xri1 here I should bind `ID` of this DropDown to `Auther_Id` , which is currently getting `0`

Comment: If you want to bind to a property named `Author_Id`, then the dropdownlist needs to have the same name - `@Html.DropDownList("Author_Id", ....)`. But read the link I gave you. Use a view model and bind to your view model and always use the strongly typed `***For()` methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yp youre correct now thats working , thanks lot , I wish you can mark as an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123634/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigning `IEnumerable<Basic>` to `ViewBag.listAuthers` and in the view attempting to cast it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which cannot be done and will fail (and result in an exception). You need to create the `SelectList` in the GET method using either

```
ViewBag.listAuthers = new SelectList(lc.GetAuthersIdName(), "ID", "Name")
```

or

```
ViewBag.listAuthers = lc.GetAuthersIdName().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
    Text = x.Name
});
```

and since you want to bind to the selected value to the `Auther_Id` property of `Book`, then your view needs to be

```
@Html.DropDownList("Auther_Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listAuthers, "---Select---")
```

or better, use the strongly typed method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Auther_Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listAuthers, "---Select---")
```

However, your editing data so you should be using a [view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and that view model will contain a property for the `SelectList` (say `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AuthorList { get; set; }` and then the view will be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Auther_Id, Model.AuthorList, "---Select---")
```

Refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for more detail on implementing the view model and the associated controller methods.